# How to replace string in collection array with MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb

I have below Mongo Collection

```
{
   "name":"test",
   "work":"BA",
   "contacts":[
      {
         "company":"xyz",
         "email":"http://www.google.com/check/com/2"
      },
      {
         "company":"xyz1",
         "email":"http://www.google.com/verify/com/4"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to replace [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) from contacts email to [www.test.com](http://www.test.com), Not complete URL only a particular string from email.
Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1

- `$indexOfCP` MongoDB >=3.6

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6234e51bf7e3c64c6511e14f)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"m": "www.google.com", "r": "www.test.com"}},
 {"$set": 
   {"contacts": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$contacts",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"email": 
               {"$let": 
                 {"vars": {"index": {"$indexOfCP": ["$$this.email", "$m"]}},
                  "in": 
                   {"$cond": 
                     [{"$eq": ["$$index", -1]}, "$$this.email",
                       {"$concat": 
                         [{"$substrCP": 
                             ["$$this.email", 0, {"$subtract": ["$$index", 0]}]},
                          "$r",
                           {"$substrCP": 
                             ["$$this.email",
                               {"$add": ["$$index", {"$strLenCP": "$m"}]},
                               {"$subtract": 
                                 [{"$strLenCP": "$$this.email"},
                                   {"$add": 
                                     ["$$index", {"$strLenCP": "$m"}]}]}]}]}]}}}}]}}}}},
 {"$unset": ["m", "r"]}])
```

Query2

- `$replaceAll` MongoDB >= 4.4

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6234e4a9f7e3c64c6511e14e)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"contacts": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$contacts",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"email": 
               {"$replaceAll": 
                 {"input": "$$this.email",
                  "find": "www.google.com",
                  "replacement": "www.test.com"}}}]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Hi Takis,
Does above query 1 code work for below URL:
http://test-test1-test2.ctest.com/ket/set instead of "www.google.com"

Comment: the first query that is for 4.2, find the index of first substring and replace it, if you mean [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6239ff98f7e3c64c6511e15d) its working. It can fail only if you have that string more than 1 time (in this case only the first occurence will be replaced).

Comment: First query is working I am getting result, sorry! I want to update the collection also with first query.

Comment: its the same, you can use pipeline update like [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=623a5444f7e3c64c6511e15e)

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks Takis but it append where we don't have contacts array in collections and it append with null like "contacts: null"

Comment: try [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=623b311ef7e3c64c6511e15f) it checks if contacts exists, else doesnt add the field

Comment: Thank you for your help now it is working, how I can do for the email also if there is no email field in array object("substrCP" created problems if email field is not present)

Comment: try [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=623c9a4df7e3c64c6511e160) i think you will be ok

Comment: Yes now everything works fine as expected, thank you for your help and guidance! Really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

4.4+ :

```
db.collection.update({
 "contacts.email": {
  $regex: "google"
 }
 },
[
 {
   $addFields: {
     contacts: {
       $map: {
         input: "$contacts",
         as: "c",
         in: {
           $mergeObjects: [
            {
              email: {
              $replaceOne: {
                input: "$$c.email",
                find: "www.google.com",
                replacement: "www.test.com"
              },    
             }
            },
            {
               company: "$$c.company"
            }
           ]
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     ])
```

Explained:

Update via aggregation pipeline using replaceOne via $map/mergeObjects

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YKmDSKpcbD0)

Comment: according to the documentation, $replaceOne exists only since mongodb 4.4, not 4.2: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceOne/

Comment: Completely correct remark , fixed immediatelly... :)